# go http template extra data leaking in the template

Tags: go, go-gin

I am creating a simple crud webapp using [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) library.I have a route setup which checks for a param `id` and if its `add` a `admin-employee-add.html` should be rendered ,else return the employee with the id if exists When i am rendering a template
of `admin-employee-add.html` the error message of `404 not found` gets leaked into it.
Here is a snapshot [image]

admin-employee-add.html

```
{{template "pageStart.html" .}}
<form class="form-horizontal admin-employee">
  <div class="row form-group">
    <label for="employeeNumber" class="col-lg-2 control-label text-right">Employee #</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <span>new</span>
    </div>
    <label for="status" class="col-lg-2 control-label text-right">Status</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <span>new</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row form-group">
    <label for="firstName" class="col-lg-2 control-label text-right">Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row form-group">
    <label for="startDate" class="col-lg-2 control-label text-right">Start Date</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <input type="date" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <label for="pto" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 text-right">PTO</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input type="number" id="pto" name="pto" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
      days
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row form-group">
    <label for="position" class="col-lg-2 control-label text-right">Position</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <select name="position" id="position" class="form-control">
        <option value="CEO">CEO</option>
        <option value="CTO">CTO</option>
        <option value="COO">COO</option>
        <option value="WorkerBee">Worker Bee</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-8">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg admin-primary">Create</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

the route which is creating an the error

```
r.GET("/employee/:id/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        id := c.Param("id")
        if id == "add" {
            c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "admin-employee-add.html", nil)
        }

        employee, ok := employees[id]

        if !ok {
            c.String(http.StatusNotFound, "404 not found", nil)
        } else {
            c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "admin-employee-edit.html", map[string]interface{}{
                "Employee": employee,
            })
        }

    })
```

The error seems to occur because gin is trying to redirect `/add` -> `/add/` but i am already using the `/add/` route in the browser.

the debug logs of gin

```
[GIN-debug] GET    /login                    --> main.registerRoutes.func2 (3 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /employee/:id/            --> main.registerRoutes.func3 (3 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /employee/:id/vacation    --> main.registerRoutes.func4 (3 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /admin/                   --> main.registerRoutes.func5 (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on :3000
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 200 with
404
[GIN] 2016/05/01 - 14:12:13 | 404 |    1.101426ms | 127.0.0.1 |   GET     /employee/add/
```

I tried changing the route to `/:id` then the error showed.

```
redirecting request 301: /employee/add/ --> /employee/add
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 200 with
404
```

NOTE : This error can be easily resolved by adding a `return` at the end of  the `if id == "add"`. but this pattern makes the code look less dry. This seems to be more of a `httprouter` issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this error can easily be resolved by adding a `return` at the end of `if id == "add"`.

`c.String` and `c.HTML` use the same `Context` `c`. Internally they are writing to the same socket ( you can think of it as a file pointer ). Hence, if you call `c.String` and then `c.HTML` or vice versa, it will append the outputs in the order called.

Looking at your code, I'd assume you want to add an employee when you see `/employee/add` i.e. present a html page to do that. And `/employee/<something-other-than-add-as-id>` which will get that and display it - in this case html to edit the employee info.

It makes sense here to add the return after the `if id == "add"` since the html generated for the two scenarios is different ( they are using different templates ). Adding a separate handler purely for `/employee/add/` is another option as well.

Comment: The problem here is the fact that the error message gets passed in the template rendered , which happens due to the chaining nature of responseWriter  . what i mean to say that first the router redirects /add/ => /add which actually writes "404 not found" to the writer and then correct response is written. I hope you see the error here.

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI I see your point. But regardless, assume the url is `/employee/add/`. Now, `id = "add"`. It will run `c.HTML` inside that if statement. Then it will check `employees["add"]` and since add isnt found, ok will be false. Then you are writing code in `c.String(http.StatusNotFound, "404 not found", nil)` . Try changing that line to `c.String(http.StatusNotFound, fmt.Sprintf("%s not found", id), nil)`. The router isn't generating a default 404 message, your code is doing that.

Comment: I have resolved the issue using the extra return but the router should have cleanly redirected the url.

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI Are you saying that it is calling the handler once, emitting html, redirecting, calling the handler again and then returning a 404 ? I think that is highly unlikely.

Comment: No ,its calling the handler twice. thats why the problem arises.

Comment: Sorry for pestering. But could you add a log or a print statement in the handler and confirm that ? I still think that's highly unlikely .